# Why is there a syntax error when I assign a variable to a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import random

myList=[]

myChicken=0
belowfifty=0

while(len(myList)!=200):
    myList.append(randint(0,100))

myChicken = [for x in myList if(x) >= 50]
belowfifty = [for x in myList if (x) <= 50]

if x in myList == overfifty:
    print(overfifty)
    print(len(overfifty))

elif x in myList == belowfifty:
    print(belowfifty)
    print(len(belowfifty))
```

It shows a syntax error for `myChicken = [for x in myList if(x) >= 50]`

Comment: That's just not correct. You need to read a tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I'm new to python and I am learning about Lists. I'm also new to this site so I just copy and pasted my code.

Comment: At least read the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Uriel Eli thank you for telling me. I never knew there was a tutorial. People need to calm down

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). List comprehensions require an expression before the "loop" part.

Also, as noted elsewhere, you don't need parentheses around if conditions in Python.

For example:

```
myChicken = [x for x in myList if x >= 50]
belowfifty = [x for x in myList if x <= 50]
```

Any expression can be used before the `for`, not just a variable reference. For example, here's how you can get the squares 0-100:

```
squares = [x*x for x in range(1, 11)]
```